# Can Thorne–Żytkow object (heavenly body) exist in universe?

Tags: astrophysics, stars, neutron-stars, stellar-physics

Can [Thorne–Żytkow object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorne%E2%80%93%C5%BBytkow_object) (heavenly body) exist in universe? It's a new concept I came across. Are there such heavenly bodies in universe? It's a heavenly body in which a neutron star is present inside a super giant star.

Comment: Have you checked [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorne%E2%80%93%C5%BBytkow_object)?

Comment: No sir I didn't see

Comment: The point is that the Wikipedia article will tell you a lot about Thorne–Żytkow objects. We expect you to have done basic research like this before posting so you can ask a better informed question. The first paragraph of the Wikipedia article answers your question: *In 2014, it was discovered that the star HV 2112 was a strong candidate but this has since been called into question*.